# When was `relatime` made the default?

Tags: filesystems, mount, kernel, stat

What is the first Linux kernel release to set `relatime` as the default mount option?

Comment: The spelling of that option is very unfortunate: I will forever parse it as a misprint of "realtime".

Answer (score 14):

I remember the change, but couldn't remember the date.
It [seems](http://lwn.net/Articles/244829/) that it was back in 2007.
According to the article, relatime was available in 2.6.20, and it became the default option a few versions after that <s>(2.6.24)</s> maybe.

**Edit:** `man mount` /relatime says 2.6.30.

From [ChangeLog-2.6.30](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/ChangeLog-2.6.30):

> ```
> commit 0a1c01c9477602ee8b44548a9405b2c1d587b5a2
> Author: Matthew Garrett <mjg@redhat.com>
> Date:   Thu Mar 26 17:53:14 2009 +0000
>
> Make relatime default
>
> Change the default behaviour of the kernel to use relatime for all
> filesystems. This can be overridden with the "strictatime" mount
> option.
>
> Signed-off-by: Matthew Garrett <mjg@redhat.com>
> Signed-off-by: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
> ```

Comment: Hmm, my CentOS 5 servers using 2.6.21 don't appear to have relatime.  Strange.

Answer (score 2):

relatime mount option is default default since RHEL/CentOS/Scientific Linux version 6 ([see here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/Relatime.html)).

If relatime option is used, the atime is updated when:

1. old atime is <= than mtime/ctime
2. at least 24 hours (hardcoded in [fs/inode.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/inode.c)) have passed since the last atime update
3. inode is dirty (or the file contents have been changed but it’s in the buffer and have not been written to the physical disk yet)