# How to ensure File System is Mounted with ' atime ' enabled ?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, timestamps

Let's run `mount`

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sdb1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda1 on /media/1 type ext3 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)
```

there is nothing in these lines that show either

```
 atime
 or
 noatime
```

the problem here is, i created folders `a` and `b` and then tried accessing them, but i can not get them to update `Access Time` so i can arrange them based on `access time`.

how exactly does one ensure the "filesystem" of the "operating system" is mounted with "atime" enabled ?

Comment: You created folders `a` and `b` on which filesystem/mount?

Comment: @Patrick, i want to see it work really, i created them on desktop, but i could create them on the usb device also.  which is the last line.

Comment: It would appear that your /home directory is ext4. I still think it's something to do with atime but the mount output would appear to be on the up and up. The answer is most likely not the: "you need X in your /etc/fstab" or you need to mount it with "atime" variety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mount output would show `noatime` if atime were disabled.

Perhaps the problem with atime is due to a filesystem that does not support it?

Comment: With recent-ish kernels and `mount` (I forget when this changed), `relatime` is the default, and does no show in the `mount` output. You have to mount with the `strictatime` option to get the old behavior with fully working atime.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know Gilles.

Answer (score 4):

By default, [since Linux 2.6.30](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17844/when-was-relatime-made-the-default/17849#17849), filesystems are mounted with the [`relatime`](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/Relatime.html) mount option. With this option, the atime is not updated when it is equal to the mtime. This is only if the `atime` option is enabled (which it is by default): under `noatime`, the atime is not updated, ever. This saves on disk writes at the expense of removing a useful feature.

The kernel reports `relatime` in `/proc/mounts`, but the `mount` utility suppresses this option from its output (because it's the default setting) since util-linux 2.13.

To fully enable access times, you need to mount the filesystem with the `strictatime` option.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/fstab` the 4th column contains the options that you want to pass the mount command for each mount.

So for this filesystem you could just append the option `atime` into the 4th column of `/etc/fstab`, then you do a remount the block device like `mount -o remount <mount point>`.