# Is there software relying on `strictatime`?

Tags: filesystems, fuse, atime

I am preparing to implement a filesystem in FUSE. Implementing only one mode would be easier. Relatime is [the default behavior](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17844/when-was-relatime-made-the-default) of all kernel implemented filesystems. Is strictatime behavior still necessary to be implemented?

**Is there any existing software that relies on strictatime behaviour?**

What I suspect is NOT broken:

- Ubuntu removes files from /tmp on reboot, and only if file is older than a specified number of days, [as answered in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up). Smallest threshold seems to be 1 day, which is fine for (24 hour) relatime.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this program is really broken by non-strict atime. Could use a confirmation.

**tmpwatch** checks files (recursively) and removes those that are older than the arbitrary amount of time given by command-line. [Man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tmpwatch) says the time given can be as short as 1 hour.

Relatime is supposed to update files after >24 hours, and not only according to docs. That 24 hour interval is [hardcoded in kernel source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238923/140054). It is not configurable.