# What happened to /proc/sys/fs/relatime_interval?

Tags: linux, filesystems, proc, atime

[According to one answer](https://serverfault.com/a/130114/318638) relatime interval can be changed by

```
echo 60 > /proc/sys/fs/relatime_interval
```

but I do not have such a file? Where did it go?

```
$ ls /proc/sys/fs
aio-max-nr         file-max          leases-enable  protected_hardlinks
aio-nr             file-nr           mqueue         protected_symlinks
binfmt_misc        inode-nr          nr_open        quota
dentry-state       inode-state       overflowgid    suid_dumpable
dir-notify-enable  inotify           overflowuid    xfs
epoll              lease-break-time  pipe-max-size
```

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, kernel 3.16.0-50-generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, there once was a RedHat-only patch that made this configurable in RedHat kernels.

Ingo Molnar [proposed something similar](http://lwn.net/Articles/244384/) in 2007, but his patch wasn't merged.

Current kernels use a fixed one-day interval, introduced by [commit 11ff6f05f1e836a6a02369a4c4b64757e484adc1](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/fs/inode.c?id=11ff6f05f1e836a6a02369a4c4b64757e484adc1) in March 2009.
Excerpt from fs/inode.c:

```
/*
 * With relative atime, only update atime if the previous atime is
 * earlier than either the ctime or mtime or if at least a day has
 * passed since the last atime update.
 */
static int relatime_need_update(struct vfsmount *mnt, struct inode *inode,
                             struct timespec now)
{

        if (!(mnt->mnt_flags & MNT_RELATIME))
                return 1;
        /*
         * Is mtime younger than atime? If yes, update atime:
         */
        if (timespec_compare(&inode->i_mtime, &inode->i_atime) >= 0)
                return 1;
        /*
         * Is ctime younger than atime? If yes, update atime:
         */
        if (timespec_compare(&inode->i_ctime, &inode->i_atime) >= 0)
                return 1;

        /*
         * Is the previous atime value older than a day? If yes,
         * update atime:
         */
        if ((long)(now.tv_sec - inode->i_atime.tv_sec) >= 24*60*60)
                return 1;
        /*
         * Good, we can skip the atime update:
         */
        return 0;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if this also depends on the filesystem used. According to `linux-4.2.4/Documentation/filesystems/ocfs2.txt`,  `OCFS2` has `atime_quantum`...